# Rust: POST request to Google CrunchBase API

Tags: post, rust, reqwest

I need help sending a POST request to Google CrunchBase. I use Rust, its reqwest crate and basic Google CrunchBase API. Please find my source code below:

```
// import necessary crates
use reqwest::header::{CONTENT_TYPE, ACCEPT};
use serde_json::{Value};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use tokio;

// use async in main function
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    // create client
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();

    // generate url
    let url = "https://api.crunchbase.com/api/v4/searches/organizations?user_key=<my_user_key>";

    // create raw string for request body
    let raw_str = r#"
        {
          "field_ids": [
            "identifier",
            "categories",
            "location_identifiers",
            "short_description",
            "rank_org"
          ],
          "order": [
            {
              "field_id": "rank_org",
              "sort": "asc"
            }
          ],
          "query": [
            {
              "type": "predicate",
              "field_id": "funding_total",
              "operator_id": "between",
              "values": [
                {
                  "value": 25000000,
                  "currency": "usd"
                },
                {
                  "value": 100000000,
                  "currency": "usd"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "predicate",
              "field_id": "location_identifiers",
              "operator_id": "includes",
              "values": [
                "6106f5dc-823e-5da8-40d7-51612c0b2c4e"
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "predicate",
              "field_id": "facet_ids",
              "operator_id": "includes",
              "values": [
                "company"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "limit": 50
        }
    "#;

    // send request, await response
    let response = client
        .post(url)
        .body(raw_str)
        .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .header(ACCEPT,       "application/json")
        .send()  // confirm request with send
        .await   // use await to yield query result
        .unwrap();

    // process response
    match response.status() {

        reqwest::StatusCode::OK => {
            println!("Success: {:?}", response);
        },
        
        reqwest::StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED => {
            println!("Error: Not authorized. New token is required.");
            println!("Response: {:?}", response);
        },

        other => {
            panic!("Error: Unexpected behaviour! {:?}", other);
        },
    };

}
```

The code compiles and runs. I can send a request, but I obtain an erroneous response:

```
Response: Response { url: Url { scheme: "https", cannot_be_a_base: false, username: "", password: None, host: Some(Domain("api.crunchbase.com")), port: None, path: "/api/v4/searches/organizations", query: Some("user_key=<my_user_key>"), fragment: None }, status: 400, headers: {"content-type": "application/json", "date": "Wed, 17 May 2023 17:43:28 GMT", "server": "openresty", "x-cb-request-took": "2", "content-length": "319", "connection": "keep-alive"} }
thread 'main' panicked at 'Error: Unexpected behaviour! 400', src/main.rs:105:13
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I think my potential errors are:

1. generating a request body from a raw string
2. using `send().await.unwrap()` methods of the `client`

Would you please double check those for me?

Comment: You should use `response.text().await.unwrap()` to see what the body of the response says on the chance it reports what the error was from.